# I am trying to match first row of one sheet against first row of another sheet and retrieving matching data

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to match the first row of one sheet with the first row of another sheet and retrieve the rest of the data of another sheet

I have stored the data of the first row in the list like this

```
    int rowCount=sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
    List<String> li=new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int x=0; x<rowCount; x++) {
        li.add(sheet.getRow(x).getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
    }
```

However, the below code is not able to compare the data of the first row with the data of the first row of another sheet

```
    sheet=workbook.getSheetAt(1);
    rowCount=sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
    for (int x=0; x<rowCount; x++) {
        System.out.println(sheet.getRow(x).getCell(0).getStringCellValue());//------------
        if (li.get(x).equalsIgnoreCase(sheet.getRow(x).getCell(0).getStringCellValue())) {
            //retrieve the data of matching row
        }
```

Please help here

Edit: I have managed to achieve but I am getting NullPointerException

```
    for (int y=0; y<rowCount; y++) {
            System.out.println(li.get(y));
            for (int z=0; z<rowCount; z++) {
                if (li.get(y).equalsIgnoreCase(sheet.getRow(z).getCell(0).getStringCellValue())) {
                    XSSFRow row=sheet.getRow(z);
                    for (int x=1; x<=row.getLastCellNum(); x++) {
                        System.out.println(row.getCell(x).getStringCellValue());
                        System.out.println("found");
//                      break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Yes, there are equalities

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems in your last code block:

1. `x <= row.getLastCellNum()`: `getLastCellNum()`returns the index of the last cell contained in this row plus one, so it must be `x < row.getLastCellNum()`. See here: [POI: getLastCellNum()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getLastCellNum--). This explains one source of `NullPointerException`.
2. Whenever you call `row.getCell(cellIndex)` you need to check if the cell is not null, before you call `getStringCellValue()`. In fact, you should also check for the cell type before calling `getStringCellValue()`, or alternatively call `toString()`.

So, assuming that cell(0) in all rows contains a string your code could look like this:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(new File("src/main/resources/sheets.xlsx"));
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        int rowCount=sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        List<String> li=new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int x=0; x<rowCount; x++) {
            li.add(sheet.getRow(x).getCell(0).toString());
        }
            
        for (int y=0; y<rowCount; y++) {
            System.out.println("Sheet1: " + li.get(y));
            for (int z=0; z<rowCount; z++) {
                if (li.get(y).equalsIgnoreCase(sheet.getRow(z).getCell(0).toString())) {
                    XSSFRow row=sheet.getRow(z);
                    for (int x=1; x < row.getLastCellNum(); x++) {
                        XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(x);
                        if (cell != null) {
                            System.out.println(row.getCell(x).toString());
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("<empty>");
                        }
                    }
                }
           }
        }
        workbook.close();
    }
```